# Selecting All Text After A "#" Symbol With Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've got this bit of jQuery with some javascript and RegEx mixed in:

```
$(function() {
    var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(" + "hashtag" + ")\\b", "gm");
    var boxLink = "<a class='taglink' onClick='tagBox()'>$1</a>"
    var html = $('body').html();
    $('body').html(html.replace(regExp, boxLink));
});

function tagBox() {
    alert("It works!")
};
```

Basically it applies $1 to everywhere that the word "hashtag" appears. Tagbox just brings up an alert that says it works. Simple enough. The change I'd like to make is one so that it won't jet select the word "hashtag", but all words with "#" symbols before them.

How can I accomplish this and work it into the script above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `$('body').html(html)` is a really bad idea. You'll recreate the DOM, and any event listeners previously bound to nodes within the old structure will no longer function. Traversing the DOM node by node is a better idea. Something like this should do the trick:

```
// Douglas Crockford's WalkTheDOM
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
  func(node);
  node = node.firstChild;
  while (node) {
    walkTheDOM(node, func);
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
}

function esc(text) {
  return text.replace(/[&<>"'`]/g, function (chr) {
    return '&#' + chr.charCodeAt(0) + ';'
  })
}

walkTheDOM(document.body, function (node) {
  if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    var html = ''
    // The even indexes contain the hashtags; the odd indexes contain
    // the text that appears between one hashtag and the next.
    // 
    // > 'This post is tagged #javascript and #jquery'.split(/(#\w+)/)
    // ["This post is tagged ", "#javascript", " and ", "#jquery", ""]
    // 
    // Text must be escaped before being inserted via `.html()`.
    $.each(node.textContent.split(/(#\w+)/), function (idx, text) {
      html += idx % 2 ? esc(text) : '<a class="taglink">' + esc(text) + '</a>'
    })
    $(node).parent().html(html)
  }
})
```

This code is untested, and no doubt has some bugs, but hopefully I've convinced you that this problem is more difficult than it may have appeared at first.

Comment: I like your approach to making it cleaner. Yeah, $('body').html(html) is awful. I tried copy/pasting your script, it doesn't highlight any hashtags and I don't understand it well enough to debug.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/green/8nKNu/12/

Comment: I decided to go recreate the DOM. BAD IDEA. Came back here, you were one step ahead of me, probably more. Thanks! Flagged as an answer.

Comment: Cool. (I'm sorry that I missed your earlier comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var regExp = new RegExp("(#\w+)", "gm");
```

If you want to select a word without #, move it in front of the (